# embedding of abelian topological group.

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

Let $A$ be an abelian topological group and let $n$ be a natural number, such that the homomorphism of topological group 
$i: A\rightarrow A$, $a\mapsto n.a$ is injective. Is it a trivial fact that $i$ is an embedding of the underlying topological spaces ?

Comment: Do you require your topological groups to be Hausdorff?  If not, there are easy counterexamples.  If so, I suspect there are still counterexamples but they seem less easy to come up with.

Comment: @EricWofsey A is Hausdorff.

Comment: A "homomorphism from $A$ to $A$" is called "endomorphism of $A$" (rather than "homomorphism of $A$").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $A=\mathbb{Z}$, with the topology given by embedding it in the product $\prod_n \mathbb{Z}/(2\cdot 3^n\mathbb{Z})$ by the quotient map on each coordinate.  (So, we have the $3$-adic topology restricted to $2\mathbb{Z}$, but $2\mathbb{Z}$ is open in $\mathbb{Z}$.)  Then multiplication by $2$ is injective on $A$, but it is not an embedding, because $2\mathbb{Z}$ is open in $A$ but its image $4\mathbb{Z}$ is not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm not familiar with 3-adic topology (Hausdorff?).. I will try to understand your example.

Answer (score 2):

There's a locally compact example: fix a prime $p$, and consider $\mathbf{Q}_p^\mathbf{N}$, endowed with the unique topology for which $\mathbf{Z}_p^\mathbf{N}$, with the (compact) product topology, is an open subgroup. (This topology is induced by the diagonal inclusion into $\mathbf{Q}_p^\mathbf{N}\times (\mathbf{Q}_p^\mathbf{N}/\mathbf{Z}_p^\mathbf{N})_{\mathrm{discrete}}$.) Then multiplication by $p$ is bijective, but is not a homeomorphism, since it maps the open subgroup $\mathbf{Z}_p^\mathbf{N}$ onto the non-open subgroup $(p\mathbf{Z}_p)^\mathbf{N}$.

The latter example is not $\sigma$-compact. Actually, every continuous isomorphism of $\sigma$-compact topological groups is a homeomorphism.

However, here's a second countable variant for the question: in the above example, restrict to the subgroup $H$ of $\mathbf{Q}_p^\mathbf{N}$ consisting of elements such that all but finitely many coordinates are in $\mathbf{Z}_p$, and all are in $p^{-1}\mathbf{Z}_p$; this is an open, second-countable subgroup. Then in $H$, multiplication by $p$ maps the whole group $H$ onto a dense proper subgroup of $\mathbf{Z}_p^\mathbf{N}$, which is not even closed.